# Need help getting my game to compile (SDL and C++. Running on Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu MATE)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, makefile, raspberry-pi

I recently tried porting over a game of mine running on Ubuntu on my main desktop over to my Raspberry Pi 3 for testing purposes. My makefile points to my own copy of SDL's libraries, so I assumed simply copying everything over would allow everything to compile and run. This is not the case.
When compiling, my linker flags pointing to the SDL libraries seem to be getting ignored:

```
Aegis: $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(OBJS) -L/sdlLib/SDL -lSDL2  -L/sdlLib -lSDL2_image -L/sdlLib -lSDL2_mixer -lX11 -o Aegis
```

in my makefile produces the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2_image
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2_mixer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
```

I've moved my libraries to the locations the linker automatically checks as well (/usr/lib, etc) but that has led to more errors and more confusion. This is something I am just learning how to do, so, rather than continuing to pound my head against the wall trying to get this method of linking to work, I'd like to find out why my linker flags to my personal copies of SDL are not working.

Comment: Did you really put the sdlLib directory in the root of your filesystem? If not those -L options are incorrect.

Comment: Did you really copy binaries from your desktop to your Raspberry Pi 3?